# Input Tag Messing Up Alignment

Tags: html, css

So, in my header, I have a horizontal list of links. Next to them, I wanted a search bar, but when I insert it next to my links, all of them now appear behind my body div.

HTML:

```
<ul id="unordered">
  <li><a href="#">LInk1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><input type="text"></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#unordered {
display:inline-block;
height:0px;
padding-bottom:5px;
margin-left:400px;
}
#unordered li a{
text-align:center;
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:18px;
list-style-type:none;
}
#unordered li {
list-style-type:none;
display:inline;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 55px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
}
#unordered li link {
list-style-type:none;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Here's screenshots of before and after...

Before: http://prntscr.com/2jfi8i
After: http://prntscr.com/2jfhxz

Thank you.

Edit: I noticed that I forgot form tags. After I inserted them, it's no longer hidden behind the body div, but the links are now above the text box.

Comment: Use jsfiddle so we could recreate the error and check if it's really because of this part of the code or for example from input styling somehwere else in your stylesheet(it can for example use display:block which shouldn't be used because inline element would have block element as a child)

Comment: You didn't close the input tag by the way

Comment: @MaciejPaprocki Input tags don't need to be closed

Comment: Hi Michael Blake, I grabbed the code you gave us and threw it into an html page and I am not getting the issue that your screenshots show. Could you include more code or create a jsfiddle for us?

Comment: One minute, I'll go ahead and try to.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7f2Ky/ 
Also, please read the edit I made to the original post. Thank you.

Comment: It's not true that input tag doesn't need to be closed. Only in html5 it's allowed to don't close it (however because of XML approach not reccomended). In Xhtml it will throw error. this same I think goes to all previous versions, and for sure to older versions of IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think what's happening is your `#unordered` is not wide enough with the position you give it. The text field shifts down. The following fixed it

```
#unordered {
display:inline-block;
height:0px;
padding-bottom:5px;
margin-left:100px; /*It's 100px instead of 400px, the ul is wider*/
}
```

There are other ways to fix it, the above is just one way.

**Update**
I removed the form tags, unless you really want those? (they were not in the original code) I then removed the `height:0px` which resolved the body appearing to be in front of the `ul` element. It was not allowing for any padding/margin below the text element. Again though, if the page stretches (the width increases) out the text input re-renders inline with the rest.

Please see [Fiddle Update](http://jsfiddle.net/7f2Ky/2/)

Comment: This worked on the web-page I made before  I saw the fiddle. I looked at the fiddle... this didn't appear to work with the rest of the html/css in the fiddle... playing with the fiddle and will make changes to the above code soon.